# Load pdf with transparent background in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, uiwebview

I've saved a pdf with transparent background with photoshop and import in xcode. 
I've create a webview and import the pdf like this:

```
NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PDF_da Photoshop" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[wv setDelegate:self];
[wv loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```

No problem to see the pdf inside the webview but without a transparent background.

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting to see the webview underneath the PDF? If so then this won't work. The way UIWebView displays PDFs is by swapping its subviews out with an entirely new view. To keep the webview underneath you will need to implement your own PDF view or find an existing library, there a few on github. A quick google brings: https://github.com/schwa/iOS-PDF-Reader and https://github.com/vfr/Reader

Comment: @JFoulkes: How can I implement my own PDF view that draws with a transparent background? Either information from the docs or an example would be really appreciated!

Comment: @Zolomon you will need to write your own PDF viewer using the CG PDF API provided by Apple - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html. Alternatively you could look into reusing one of the open source libraries in my original answer to use a transparent background